# Ajax PHP form button

Tags: php, html, ajax

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here please?

Here is the basic HTML file with a simple "Create" and "Destroy" button that will eventually call an API. The button click with Ajax seems to work, but the PHP function is not being called.

***testapi.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            alert("Action performed successfully!");
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="create" value="Create" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="destroy" value="Destroy" />
</body>
</html>
```

***ajax.php***

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'create':
            create();
            break;
        case 'destroy':
            destroy();
            break;
    }
}
function create() {
    echo "Create function.";
    exit;
}
function destroy() {
    echo "Destroy function.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: `else { echo "Not set"; }` add that to your `if` statement; does it go there?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Great idea! Did not seem to make a difference. I am not seeing any output.

Comment: No I have not watched. I forgot I could do that, let me figure out how to bring that up. Yes look in the head of html. Yes, running on a webserver. No errors reported, just no output.

Comment: BTW, to answer your comment: questions starting like this: *"Can anyone tell me what I am missing here please?"* tend to attract downvotes because telling you what you're missing might require a crystal ball.

Comment: Case? Your input has `value="Create"`, your code checks for `case 'create':`

Comment: Hmm, looking at the console and I see now under the response that I am getting "Create function." which tells me it is working, its just not echoing that to the screen.

Comment: You don't have anything in your AJAX to echo it to the screen. All you have is an alert. Change that to `alert(response);` and see what happens

Comment: @Kerbholz, you were correct. Correct the case issue and the function is running now. So it was a two part issue. The case was preventing the function from running and apparently I dont yet fully understand ajax. How do I get it to then echo in ajax?

Comment: Read the link in my comment above - it describes the process for updating the local web page with returned data.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard FIXED! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Both issues now fixed and the code is running properly!

Comment: Please post a proper answer and mark as accepted.

Comment: Always use a `default:` switch case ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is wrong: the value in your input is `Create`, while in your code you check for `create`.

Change

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'create':
            create();
            break;
        case 'destroy':
            destroy();
            break;
    }
```

to

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'Create':
            create();
            break;
        case 'Destroy':
            destroy();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it nicer to lowercase the `$_POST['action']`? e.g. `strtolower($_POST['action'])`

Comment: Yes, would be nicer ;)